# Make top 50 users who received the most points

Tags: sql, database

madam,

I would like to make a top 50 of users who received the most points.
So my database table looks like this:

points table:
pid | uid_give | uid | amount | time

(every row indicates an amount given)

Now I want to make a top 50 of users who received the most amount.
I had the sql query but dont remeber to do this.
Can you help? (group by?)

Regards,

Comment: Could you please provide sample data,desired result and database name, as the question of TOP N can be solved in different way in different RDBMSes

Comment: which database you are using?

Comment: I found the answer my own thank you

Answer (score 1):

in mysql

```
select id, uid_give,  uid, amount, time from points order by amount desc limit 50;
```

in sql server

```
select top 50 id, uid_give,  uid, amount, time from points order by amount desc ;
```

Oracle 12 and onward

```
select id, uid_give,  uid, amount, time from points order by amount desc 
FETCH FIRST 50 ROWS ONLY;
```